# Facebook GraphAPI publishing check-ins

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having issues with Facebook Graph API's check-in which can be tested here
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

running the request on it's page ID shows that the can_checkin property is true
/v2.4/113779602031343?fields=can_checkin

But when attempting to publish with following request:

POST /v2.4/me/feed

place: 113779602031343

It does this:

[image: Image showing facebook post without place attached]

I'm able to do successful posts using other pages and it gives the expected output of:
[image: Image showing facebook post with place attached]

Hopefully someone with a bit more Facebook API experience can shed some light on why it's working for one and not the other.. I was hoping the "can_checkin" property would solve it for me.

Comment: Doesn’t work for me either, not even if I add a message to the post. From what I can see in Graph API Explorer and on the FB page itself, I can’t spot anything that would prevent this from working (page seems to be public, and has an address set, and a `location` showing up via API) – so I can only suggest you file a bug report, and ask them why this is not working. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll do that

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?